# Perl Checksum Calculation Migration to Java

Tags: java, perl, checksum

I am tasked to migrate a Perl program to java.

And I am having some trouble, there is a function in Perl to calculate the checksum

```
sub ComputeChecksum  {
   my ($val) = @_;

   $value= 0;
   $multiplier = 1;

   $dlength=length($val);
   for($i=0; $i<$dlength; $i++) {
      $ival=ord(substr($val, $i, 1));
      $ival*=$multiplier;
      $value+=$ival/100000;
      $value+=$ival%100000;
      $multiplier%=2;
      $multiplier++;
   }
   $value%=100000;
   $value=(100000-$value)%100000;
   return ($value);
}
```

I translated this code into java as shown bellow

```
private static long computeCheckSum(String id){
    long value = 0;
    long multiplier = 1;

    int dlength = id.length();

    for(int i=0; i< dlength; i++){
        int ival = id.charAt(i);
        ival *= multiplier;
        value += ival/100000;
        value += ival%100000;
        multiplier %= 2;
        multiplier++;
    }
    value %= 100000;
    value = ((100000-value)%100000);

    return value;
}
```

But I am running into an issue when validating old data that is in the database, around 5% of the time the calculated checksum in java does not match the one calculated by Perl previously, and it missed by 1.

Here are some examples of the old data and the results in java

```
                                 Perl    Java
ff08ccfba8ad417db2857fc8933788af:96410 / 96409
ff163b2b2e3ef18265d08cc8965b864d:96533 / 96532
ff3848ff301b534b609148af93b2c9ce:96626 / 96625
ff48ec78ea190f44233c9050fd73137d:96631 / 96630
ff62234601e28e6f5d7ff89d95afbec0:96424 / 96423
ff78f4cabe5a565a1cdf11f752f13654:96495 / 96494
ff89dc6b86a535ef265727af90a9b6b3:96596 / 96595
ff98337de5eb9e60f1db51dbd14a4dd2:96366 / 96365
fff76022c6f9f7794793141a9f2a00d2:96813 / 96812
```

In these sets the first part is the data in the database, which is composed of a uid, an semicolon and the calculated checksum by Perl this is how the data is saved in the database.

For comparison i added the slash and the result calculated by my java code using the uid part.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this could be happening?
I need to be able to calculate the correct checksum 100% of the time.

======================================================================

Update :

I changed my java code, to do all calculations in float, instead of int, and it came out more interesting, the difference, was in the same group of uids, but instead of generating a difference of 1, it was a difference of 2.

I am thinking of proposing a recalculation of the checksum of all the UID, and updating all the tables that are affected.

Comment: I tested all your strings and got the same result in java as in perl. Btw, why not use a standard checksum function?

Comment: Does the database contain any non-ascii characters? Outside 32..126 that is

Comment: Try reducing each failing case to the smallest string that exhibits the failure by removing one character at a time.  See if there is a pattern in the boundary

Comment: @TedLyngmo i came in new, the person who wrote this code was fired, and now I am in charge of refactoring this code to java, but keeping the functionality working.
And the checksum is needed so i can retrieve the records because my input is just the uid

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen none, all characters are ascii

Comment: @rread I see. It's strange that I get the same result in perl and java. I get the number you've listed in the Java column .

Comment: Why did you change my edit to put "Java" over the column of Perl results?

Comment: @ikegami Do you get different results in java and perl for the data listed in the question? I get exactly the same (the value in the rightmost column - whatever the header happens to be). Perl 5.32.1 and javac 11.0.11.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, I get the right column for Perl. Haven't run Java. And there's noting platform or version specific on the Perl side. (Well, when `$value` "overflows" would change, but that would take a much much much longer string.)

Comment: @ikegami I thought not but just wanted to make sure. I find it very odd that OP gets different results - and +1 seems like a very specific number. If I add `"\0x01"` to the string before calculating the checksum the result gets -1 instead. At first I thought a null had sneaked in but null doesn't affect the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Printing `$ival/100000` for `ff08ccfba8ad417db2857fc8933788af` gives the following:

```
0.00102
0.00204
0.00048
0.00112
...
```

I don't know if the division is an integer division or not in the Java program, but it amounts to adding zero either way. This is a difference.

By the way, I suspect the Perl program is the buggy one. I suspect integer division was desired (`int($ival/100000)`), but floating point division was accidentally used.

That said, for the numbers you provided, the difference doesn't seem significant enough to have a result i.e. using `int($ival/100000)` produces the same result as `$ival/100000`. There is apparently another difference.

---

...or is there? Adding

```perl
while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   say $_, ":", ComputeChecksum($_);
}

__DATA__
ff08ccfba8ad417db2857fc8933788af
ff163b2b2e3ef18265d08cc8965b864d
ff3848ff301b534b609148af93b2c9ce
ff48ec78ea190f44233c9050fd73137d
ff62234601e28e6f5d7ff89d95afbec0
ff78f4cabe5a565a1cdf11f752f13654
ff89dc6b86a535ef265727af90a9b6b3
ff98337de5eb9e60f1db51dbd14a4dd2
fff76022c6f9f7794793141a9f2a00d2
```

I get what you say are the Java results (even with `$ival/100000`):

```
ff08ccfba8ad417db2857fc8933788af:96409
ff163b2b2e3ef18265d08cc8965b864d:96532
ff3848ff301b534b609148af93b2c9ce:96625
ff48ec78ea190f44233c9050fd73137d:96630
ff62234601e28e6f5d7ff89d95afbec0:96423
ff78f4cabe5a565a1cdf11f752f13654:96494
ff89dc6b86a535ef265727af90a9b6b3:96595
ff98337de5eb9e60f1db51dbd14a4dd2:96365
fff76022c6f9f7794793141a9f2a00d2:96812
```

Comment: As both arguments are `int`s in Java it is integer division.  Nice catch.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I suspected as much. But even if it was FP div, the result would get truncated as its added to a `long`. The problem happens either way